# Debugging in webstorm to debug when you are running through a grunt connect server?

Tags: webstorm

I can debug js files by running them in the browser in webstorm. but how do you get to hit breakpoints inside webstorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run/debug your server code executed by Grunt using Node.js run configuration. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233279/how-to-debug-grunt-in-phpstorm-webstorm), for example

Comment: so any client side angular code that is being run in this server will be hit?

Comment: to debug a client-side code, you need a javascript debug run configuration. You can either create it manually and run after your node.js configuration, or enable 'After launch' and 'with javascript debugger' options in Browser/Live Edit tab of your Node.js run configuration. Of course, you would need to specify the appripriate URL in the edit field